# Skip self-asserted orchestration step if claims exist not working

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

This is in reference to custom policy signupsignin user journey. 
I have a self-asserted orchestration step that collects users email address before the combined signupsignin orchestration step. 
I'm wanting to skip this step if the users claims already exist

This is necessary when collecting refresh tokens.
Here's how I have the orchestration step coded.

```xml
<OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="ClaimsExchange" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.selfasserted.email">
  <Preconditions>
     <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
          <Value>objectId</Value>
          <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
    </Precondition>
  </Preconditions>
  <ClaimsExchanges>
    <ClaimsExchange Id="SelfAssertedEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-CollectEmailAddress-NoError" />
  </ClaimsExchanges>
</OrchestrationStep>
```

Comment: Hi @Chris Harris. Can you please confirm that this is related to a token refresh?

Comment: Expected Behavior: If a user is logged into the authority, then subsequent login attempts (both with no prompt parameter or with prompt=none) should redirect back with 302 Found (or a series of 302 Found) with new tokens.

Actual Behavior: The login attempt stays on b2clogin (even with prompt=none), expecting a field to be filled out and the “continue” button clicked.  Afterward, (on what would be the username/password step) it automatically redirects back with the new token.

Comment: Thank you, @Chris Harris, this might be related to the SSO session then. Does the **SelfAsserted-CollectEmailAddress-NoError** technical profile reference [the **SM-AAD** technical profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-sso-custom#defaultssosessionprovider) for `<UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement />`?

Comment: It references AAD-UserReadUsingEmailAddress-NoError in the validationtechnicalprofiles section,  which references AAD-Common.

Comment: i was able to get the prompt=none to behave as expected based on your input Chris, thanks!  Step 1 is still getting executed when i remove the prompt=none though.  Still working through why this is.

Comment: correction, the prompt=none was not working either. i was getting a 302 found but the response header had an AADB2C90037 Error while processing your request error message.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this might be happening because the **SelfAsserted-CollectEmailAddress-NoError** technical profile isn't "participating" in the SSO session; therefore it prompts the same user in the same session for the e-mail address again.

For the **SelfAsserted-CollectEmailAddress-NoError** technical profile to participate in the SSO session, ensure this technical profile contains the `<UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement />` element as follows:

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-CollectEmailAddress-NoError">
  ...
  <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
    <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingEmailAddress-NoError" />
  </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
  <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-AAD" />
</TechnicalProfile>
```